# Visualizing the output of a Voronoi diagram computation

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, computational-geometry

I need to plot a graph (to be specific: Fortune Algorithm output) with given vertex coordinates and a few unconnected vertices. I am thinking of using Mathematica for that.

`GraphPlot` does much of the task with `VertexCordinateRules` option but does not plot unconnected points.

1. So is there any way to do this?
   And it would be even nicer if that graph comes with 2-D Axes. I was thinking to use `ListLinePlot` and `Point` commands but they give two different graphs as output.
2. Is there any option for combining output from two graphs? (The `Show` command didn't help.)

Comment: What version do you have?  In version 8 you can use `Graph` instead of `GraphPlot`.  Is your aim to construct an actual graph, or do you merely want to plot the result (and don't want to use it in a graph-context)?

Comment: I do have version 8, but Graph command doesn't seems to plot unconnected vertices. I don't think Computational geometry package will be helpful as I am looking for visualization only.

Comment: Actually, using adjacency matrix and graph plot I am able to plot unconnected vertices but the sense of Voronoi diagram is lost as graph plot does not follow coordinates systems(i.e. no directional or distance correctness).

Comment: @samikaran-theequation Just post a sample input dataset (in the format you have it in in Mathematica) and I'll show you how.

Comment: the option i was looking for is UndirectedEdge[] in graph command. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I didn't quite follow the description of your graph, but are you aware of this functionality?:

```
data = MapIndexed[Flatten[{##}] &, RandomReal[1, {100, 2}]];

ListDensityPlot[
 data,
 InterpolationOrder -> 0,
 ColorFunction -> Hue,
 Mesh -> All,
 Epilog -> Point@data[[All, {1, 2}]]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Specifically note `InterpolationOrder -> 0`.

Comment: The ComputationalGeometry package has Voronoi diagrams as well.  I think he's looking to visualize them only, not to compute them (suppose you'd make your own program for computing them, for whatever reason, then you need to visualize the result quickly)

Comment: You're not very active lately, what happened?  I'm hoping for the glorious return of Spartacus! :D

Comment: Yup, I am looking just to plot my result of Voronoi diagram and not to compute them. Lets say; a={1,2};b={4,2};c={3,0};d={3,7}. So is there a way to plot an edge(c,d) and points a and b?

Comment: @Szabolcs other hobbies. :-)

Comment: Do you mean something like this? Graph[{a, b, c, d}, {UndirectedEdge[c,d]}, 
 VertexCoordinates -> {{1, 2}, {4, 2}, {3, 0}, {3, 7}}]

Comment: This is, very much what I want. Though its odd how above command considers c={1,2} d={4,2} a={3,0} & b={3,7} (guess its mathematica bug!!?) but its nice that vertices are plotted proportionally to their coordinates.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a nice clean way to both compute and plot the Voronoi diagram with some undocumented functions:

```
Graphics`Region`RegionInit[];
```

Then:

```
pts = RandomReal[6, {100, 2}];

Show[GeometryPlot[VoronoiMesh[pts], Mesh -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.3], Yellow}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Darker@Green, Dashed}], Graphics[{Red, Point[pts]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

Now in Mathematica 10, [VoronoiMesh](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VoronoiMesh.html) is a standard built in function.

```
pts=RandomReal[{-1,1},{25,2}];
Show[VoronoiMesh[pts]
    ,Graphics[{Red,Point[pts]}]
    ,Frame-> True
]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I'm curious as no example was shown in the documentation. Does `VoronoiMesh` compute 3D Voronoi diagrams?

Comment: @RunnyKine tks. I see 3D in [DelaunayMesh](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DelaunayMesh.html) but not for VoronoiMesh. Maybe under implementation.